# How to blur content after ajax call

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, dom-events

I'm using ajax call on my page which changes content of a division block.
What I wanted is to make that div content blur until new content loaded.

So,

Step 1 : click on button.

Step 2 : blur the content of that division block and user can't select anything now from that division.

Step 3 : Content loaded and gets back to normal state.

Step 1 and 3 are already done. What I need is step 2.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your main content block has the id 'main'.

in your button's onclick, before loading content etc.. do:

```
var pos = $('#main').offset();
var size = { w: $('#main').outerWidth(), h: $('#main').outerHeight() };
$('<div class="main_overlay"></div>')
  .css({left: pos.left+'px', top: pos.top+'px', width: size.w+'px', height: size.h+'px'})
  .appendTo('body');
```

in your css file, add:

```
.main_overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

once, everything is loaded up, and you are ready to unblur, do:

```
$('.main_overlay').remove();
```

Comment: The answer assumes you are using jQuery. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, the [ShowLoading plugin](http://contextllc.com/tools/jQuery-showLoading) does a good job of this.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function with `onreadystatechange` and set a blur to that area until `readystate==4`. Now the type of blur and how you want that done would be up to you but I used a similar idea to fade text in and out for an ajax call with my fade function in something like this.